# How to adjust the size of popup image in leaflet map in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-mapview

There is a similar question for R shiny here:[Control the size of popupImage from leaflet in r shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523494/control-the-size-of-popupimage-from-leaflet-in-r-shiny)

But I am using **flexdashboard**. I have no background in CSS. How can I adjust the size? Sample code below:

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>% 
  addRectangles(
    lng1 = bbox_north2$p1$long, lat1 = bbox_north2$p1$lat,
    lng2 = bbox_north2$p2$long, lat2 = bbox_north2$p2$lat,
    fillColor = "red", stroke = FALSE,
    popup = popupImage(here::here("products", "north1.png"), width = 800, height = 600, embed = TRUE)
```

When setting `width = 800`, the popup displays larger, but a portion of it is greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: mapview developer here.

First of all, please note that the `popup*()` functions from mapview have been moved to a more light-weight package called **leafpop**. Though on CRAN, for this problem we need the development version from github which can be found [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafpop). - Uncomment the `remotes::install_githib()` call in the example below to get the latest version.

There have been numerous issues with the mapview popup functions that have lead me to rewrite most of them (including `popupImage()`). The rewriting introduces a new API design which is necessary as we need to have access to the `map` object. So for your issue at hand, the following should remedy your problem:

```
# remotes::install_github("r-spatial/leafpop")
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)

img = "/path/to/some/image.png"

# does not work properly - image is clipped in y
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = franconia[1, ], popup = popupImage(img, width = 400))

# works
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = franconia[1, ], group = "fran") %>%
  addPopupImages(image = img, group = "fran", width = 400)
```

Basically, you first create the (data) layer with the respective `leaflet::add*()` function (in the example case above `addPolygons()`) and then register the images as popups using `addPopupImges()` identifying the layer with the `group` argument. This should enable you to set whatever width and height you want (though I think the maxwidth value is 2000 pixels).

Comment: Thank you for creating `leafpop`. I am trying to install it but getting compilation error. So, I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/r-spatial/leafpop/issues/6